# "Scripting" with C++ coroutines

Tags: c++, c++20, coroutine, c++-coroutine

I'm trying to implement a simple scripting system for game enemies using coroutines as behavior scripts. As many average C++ coders, I'm having hard time wading through convoluted `std::coroutine` stuff but I managed to patch up something that works. My scripts now looks like this, where `R` and `A` are return and awaiter types pasted from one of coroutine tutorials:

```
R script(){
    command_moveTo(10, 10);
    co_await A;
    command_idle(3);
    co_await A;
    command_moveTo(20, 20)
    co_await A;
    // etc..    
}
```

This does the job but I'd like to eliminate the need to constantly write `co_await` after each `command_*()` call, so the scripts look tidy like this:

```
R script(){
    command_moveTo(10, 10);
    command_idle(3);
    command_moveTo(20, 20)
    // etc..    
}
```

Is there a way to somehow suspend the coroutine from within `command_*()` functions. The complexity of `sdt::coroutine` is often justified by saying it facilitates making any kind of coroutine system. Can this rather typical use be implemented?

The only thing I could come up with is using macros for `command_*()` functions that simply sneak in `co_await` into coroutine's source code. Is there a better way?

Comment: It isn't clear why you want this to be a coroutine to begin with. It also isn't clear why you're `co_await`ing on `A`. It seems more likely that you want `co_yield`, as this is meant to communicate directly with the caller.

Comment: I want it to be a coroutine because each of those commands take some (possibly long) time to finish e.g. moving to some coordinates takes time. It basically works like a sequencer. When a command is issued the coroutine is suspended until the main code (that runs in an endless loop) is done executing the command. After that, the coroutine is resumed and the next command is executed. Coroutines are quite convenient for this. I used Python's greenlet before in similar fashion.

Answer (score 2):

A coroutine can only suspend itself by using `co_await` or similar syntax. Nothing outside a coroutine, even a function it calls, can force it to suspend.

If all of these `command_` functions are intended to be followed by a `co_await` call, then you should have them *return* the awaitable. This means you invoke `co_await command_*`. And set the functions to be `[[nodiscard]]`, so users can't call them without doing something with the return value.

This also allows the command to have a say in when it is finished and the next command should be executed. You could even make the awaitable something you can chain, so that you can have multiple commands that will be considered finished when all of them are finished.

```
co_await command_moveTo(10, 10) & command_idle(3);
```

Comment: Thanks! I guess I'll take `co_await command_*()` as the shortest possible syntax for this. Not as clean looking as I was hoping for, but close enough.